# Question about the pullback of the Riemann metric via the exponential map.

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

I want to ask a question about the pullback of the Riemann metric with the map being the exponential map.

Given a Riemannian manifold $(M,g)$,  and an exponential map $f_\alpha: B_1 \rightarrow M$ which is given by $$f_\alpha(x):=\exp _{x_0}(\alpha x),$$
where $\exp _p$ is the exponential map at $p$, then define $$h_\alpha:=\alpha^{-2} f_\alpha^* g,$$
which is a  metric on $B_1$.

How to prove that $$
h_{\alpha, i j}=\alpha^{-2} g_{i j},
$$
when $M$ is $S^2$, we can do some calculations:

Let $x_0$ be the north pole of $S^2$. Write $v \in T_{x_0} S^2$ as $v=t(\cos \theta, \sin \theta)$, the $(\phi, \theta)$ coordinates of $\exp _{x_0}(\alpha v)$ are $\phi=\alpha t$, $\theta=\theta$.

Take the induced metric on $S^2$ from pullback of metric on $\mathbb{R}^3$, so the metric is $$d s^2=d \phi \otimes d \phi+\sin ^2 \phi d \theta \otimes d \theta,$$ so
$$f_{\alpha}:(t,\theta) \rightarrow (\phi,\theta),$$
with $(t,\theta)$ being $(x_1,x_2)$ and $(\phi,\theta)$ being $(y_1,y_2)$, and
$$
\left(f_{\alpha}^* g\right)_{\mu \nu}=\frac{\partial y^\alpha}{\partial x^\mu} \frac{\partial y^\beta}{\partial x^\nu} g_{\alpha \beta}
$$
then
$$\left(f_\alpha^* g\right)_{1 1}=\alpha^2 g_{11}, \left(f_\alpha^* g\right)_{1 2}=\left(f_\alpha^* g\right)_{2 1}=0, \left(f_\alpha^* g\right)_{22}=g_{22},$$
so
$$h_\alpha=\alpha^{-2}\left(\alpha^2 d t \otimes d t+\sin ^2(\alpha t) d \theta \otimes d \theta\right) ,$$ so $h_{\alpha, i j}=\alpha^{-2} g_{i j}$ as desired.

But what about when $M$ is not something we could calculate? I have no idea about this. This seems to be fundamental but I just don't know.

**Update:** **Is it because that given a map $M \rightarrow \tilde{M}$, the pushforward of basis vectors of $T_p(M)$ are indeed the basis vectors of $T_q(\tilde{M})$?**

Comment: The question doesn't quite make sense. $h_\alpha$ is a metric on $B_1\subset T_{x_0}M$, but $g$ is a metric on $M$. I think you mean $h_\alpha|_{x_0}=\alpha^{2} g|_{x_0}$, where the two tangent spaces are identified. Also I think the power should be $\alpha^2$ not $\alpha^{-2}$. This already shows in your calculation for $S^2$. In any event, I think in general, it boils down to that $x\to \alpha x$ scales the metric by $\alpha^2$. So if you pullback using $f_1$ with $\alpha=1$, you get $h_1=g$ at the point. Hence in general, the scaling.

Comment: I see, since $\phi=\alpha t$, if I write $d s^2=d \phi \otimes d \phi+\sin ^2 \phi d \theta \otimes d \theta$ as $d s^2=\alpha^2 d t \otimes d t+\sin ^2 (\alpha t) d \theta \otimes d \theta$, then it's just a scaling, $h_\alpha=\alpha^{-2}\left(\alpha^2 d t \otimes d t+\sin ^2(\alpha t) d \theta \otimes d \theta\right)$, so $h_{\alpha, i j}=\alpha^{-2} g_{i j}$. Thanks for pointing out my problem!

Comment: This arises from a paper, the author took $\alpha \rightarrow 0$ to make $h_{\alpha} \rightarrow|d x|^2$ as $\alpha \rightarrow 0$.

Comment: Now this statement $h_\alpha\to |dx|^2$ makes sense, and it explains the definition $h_\alpha = \alpha^{-2}f_\alpha^*g$. You can clearly see this in your $S^2$ example, since $h_\alpha\to dt\otimes dt + t^2 d\theta\otimes d\theta$, the Euclidean metric. Good!